# What's the meaning of 私でもたまに in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning, set-phrases

I'm a bit confused about this sentence:

> 斜陽の日本語は、私でもたまに難しい

This part is easy: 斜陽の日本語は. It means "the Japanese (language) in (the book) The Setting Sun ..."

But this second bit confuses me a lot: 私でもたまに.  I read it as: "I ... but occasionally ... difficult." What?

What's the meaning of 私でもたまに in this sentence?

(Maybe it means "but occasionally, I find it difficult?" If that's the case, shouldn't でも be placed before 私?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This usage of でも is the て form of です plus も 'even'.

Some examples (from Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar):

> 先生でも間違います。
>
> Even a teacher makes mistakes.
>
> 私は難しい仕事でもします。
>
> I will even do a difficult job.
>
> ここからでも富士山が見えます。
>
> Even from here you can see Mt. Fuji.

Therefore, 私でも is something like "even if it's me".

Putting it all together, we could translate it to something like:

> The Japanese (language) in (the book) The Setting Sun, even to me is occasionally difficult.

Comment: More precisely, a form of だ.  The て form of です is でして.

Comment: Thanks. So "but" and "even"  can be written in the same way ... but then how to tell if it's "but or "even"?

Comment: @alex The same way you tell apart *bear* and *bear*.  Context.